# Design patterns: Using es6 export const for dependency injection

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

I'been thinking about the idea to implement **dependency injection** in my express app  built using es6. 
The actual project looks like this:

**/controllers/myController.controller.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import MyModel from '/models/myModel.model.js';

class MyController{
  constructor(){
    this.router = express.Router();
  }
  getAll(){
    var modelInstance = new MyModel();
    this.router.get('/', (req , res) => {
      res.send(modelInstance.getData());
    });
  }
}
```

**/models/myModel.model.js**

```
export class MyModel{
  constructor(){
  }
  getData(){
    return 'it\'s working';
  }
}
```

But i think that a better idea is export a instance of class like this:

**/models/myModel.model.js**

```
class MyModel{
  constructor(){
  }
  getData(){
    return 'it\'s working';
  }
}
//export a new instance
export const ModelInstance = new MyModel();
```

And then modify the controller like this

**/controllers/myController.controller.js**

```
import express from 'express';
//inject a new instance of the model
import {modelInstance} from '/models/myModel.model.js';

class MyController{
  constructor(){
    this.router = express.Router();
  }
  getAll(){
    this.router.get('/', (req , res) => {
      res.send(modelInstance.getData());
    });
  }
}
```

I don't know if my idea it is correct, but i think that this example it's a good application about this pattern.

**What do you think about this?**

Comment: You have invented a singleton.

Comment: @zerkms isn't a factory?

Comment: `export const ModelInstance = new MyModel();` --- it's not, you create a single instance and provide global access to it.

Comment: @zerkms Oh, thanks. I tested it and you're right. It's a singleton!

Comment: @zerkms How i can export following the factory pattern?

Comment: `export default class MyModel`? Why not simply export a constructor? Not sure what "the factory pattern" means though - the "classical" design patterns don't describe one (there are the abstract factory and the factory method design patterns though).

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the `class` syntax is syntactic sugar for the good old `prototype`, I don't see the point of instantiating a single `MyModel`, I think you'd rather use `Object` (`{}`) for singletons:

```
export const myInstance = {
  getData() {
    return 'it\'s working';
  }
}
```

By the way, what did you mean with dependency injection? There is none in this code but you can read more about it [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Dependency-injection-in-JavaScript)

Comment: "Considering that the class syntax is syntactic sugar for the good old prototype" --- it is harmful to treat it like so. Consider JS is a syntactic sugar over CPU instructions and electric signals.

Comment: @zerkms Oh come on. As long as you're being pedantic, what you really mean is that the JS is syntactic sugar over the JS engine, which is syntactic sugar over whatever it was implemented in, which is syntactic sugar over the processor's instruction set, which is syntactic sugar over its microcode, which is syntactic sugar over its hardware, etc. But what's the point? ES2015 classes are syntactic sugar over JS's OOP. For the purposes of this question, that's the level of abstraction necessary.

Comment: "But what's the point?" --- the point is that it's a different abstraction and it does not really matter how it is implemented under the hood.

Comment: @DaveNewton "ES2015 classes are syntactic sugar over JS's OOP" --- and it is harmful to treat it like so. I really have no clue why people deliberately destroy useful abstractions. Everything is just bits.

Comment: @zerkms So code your websites in FPGAs (without Verilog or VHDL, obviously). I have better things to do with my time, like use useful abstractions when it makes sense to do so. YMMV.

Comment: "I don't see the point of instantiating a single MyModel" --- the point is type system. `ModelInstance` from OPs code is typed, and the POJO you're returning is not.